# Qual a melhor forma de salvar uma imagem no MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, imagem, servidor, upload, mongodb

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JS com servidor Node e preciso salvar imagens no MongoDB da forma que economize o maior espaço possível, e atualmente estou convertendo a imagem para String base64 e salvando como atributo de um documento na collection.

Porém, com poucas fotos(Full HD, 4K, 8K) logo o banco estava com 350MB de tamanho, foi algo em torno de umas 15 fotos.

Alem desse método tem aquele outro em que é feito upload da imagem para uma pasta do servidor e é somente salvo o caminho e o nome da imagem.

Quero economizar o espaço do servidor pois o mesmo será implantado no Google Cloud Platform, e não quero ter custos a mais somente por causa de fotos.

A minha dúvida é: **Quais métodos além dos citados acima existem para salvar uma imagem no MongoDB da forma mais eficiente possível??**

Obs.: Não tenho como postar o código pois tenho ele somente no computador da empresa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na documentação do mongoDb, eles recomendam usar ["GridFs"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) quando a imagem passa de 16mb.

Comment: Estudei mais a fundo a situação e vi que a principal prática utilizada é utilizar os storages disponibilizados (S3 na Amazon, Container no Azure e por aí vai).

Mas agradeço a sua ajuda, vou pesquisar sobre isso também...

Comment: Eu recomendo o Azure (Eu uso ele atualmente), e se estiver usando c# no backend recomendo a criacao de webjobs.

Comment: Estou assistindo as vídeoaulas do Balta.io no Youtube e lá ele também usa o Azure, vou testar e ver o que acontece

Answer (score 1):

acho que converter em base64 pode ser um agravante em seu código, independentemente de usar gridfs, armazenar em formato binário já deve ajudar bastante, dê uma olhada em outra resposta que dei, lá mostra como guardar em binário.

[upload de imagem com meteor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104884/upload-de-imagem-com-meteor/265456#265456)